# In python, how do you input data from a list into a linux command?

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to write a simple script that takes a list of words I've created in a text file on linux and runs it through a program that checks the word against a steganography extractor.

The program (steghide) uses the following syntax in the command:

> steghide --extract -p {password here} -sf {filename here}

I've been able to call the file and set up a for loop for the words in the list, but can not find a way to input the word from that iteration into each command.

Here's how I've been trying to work it.

```
import os
import sys

script, filename = argv
filename2 = sys.open(filename)

for word in filename2:
    os.system('steghide --extract -p [want to put something here] -sf stegfilename')
```

I'm on a controlled box and can't download anything beyond what I already have. Any help is appreciated.

Update:

I got it to work. But now I'm trying to get it to exit out if it finds the correct answer. I am just having a hard time getting Python to read the output. Here's what I have so far.

`import subprocess
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
passes = filename

with open(passes) as f:
    for line in f:
        proc = subprocess.popen(['steghide', '--extract', '-p' line.strip(), '-sf', 'stegged file name'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout = proc.communicate()[0]
        output = proc.stdout.readline()

```
    if 'wrote' in output:
        print 'YOU FOUND IT!'
        break
    else:
        print line`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good time to learn [string formating options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) in Python. They let you insert values dynamically into a string. An example:

```
"This {0} is an example".format([1,2,3])
>>>> "This [1,2,3] is an example"
```

In this particular case, you want to do

```
value = 'foo' # the item you want to insert - replace with list, number, etc.
...
for word in filename2:
    os.system('steghide --extract -p {0} -sf stegfilename'.format(value))
```

This will insert the value into your string, and then call `steghide` on that string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `subprocess` module instead; it gives you more options/control and `os.system()` is deprecated.

```
import subproces
with open(filename, "r") as f:
    # assumes that you have one word per line
    for line in f:
        subprocess.call(['steghide', '--extract', '-p', line.strip(), '-sf', stegfilename])
        # or if you want the output of running Niels Provos' cool, old tool :)
        cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(['steghide', '--extract', '-p', line.strip(), '-sf', stegfilename])
```

Comment: I got it to work, but now I'm trying to get it to exit once it finds the correct password. Here's what I have so far.                      import subprocess
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv
passes = filename

with open(passes) as f:
 for line in f:
  proc = subprocess.popen(['steghide', '--extract', '-p' line.strip(), '-sf', 'stegged file name'],stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
  stdout = proc.communicate()[0]
  output = proc.stdout.readline()
 
  if 'wrote' in output:
   print 'YOU FOUND IT!'
   break
  else:
   print line

Comment: @Brad `steghide` follows C/Unix conventions and returns 0 if successful, 1 if not. Use that along with `subprocess.call` to `break` on success (`subprocess.call` returns the return code of the process). No need for `subprocess.PIPE`, `proc.communicate()[0]` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) passing a list of args:

```
from subprocess import check_call


for word in map(str.rstrip, filename2):    
    check_call(['steghide', "--extract", "-p", word, "-sf", "stegfilename'"])
```

Answer (score 0):

String formatting is the subject here.

```
import os
import sys

script, filename = argv
filename2 = sys.open(filename)

for word in filename2:
    os.system('steghide --extract -p ' +[want to put something here]+ '-sf stegfilename')
```

Answer (score 0):

To join all elements of a list in a string, try python [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
'  '.join(your_variable)
```

Example:

```
var = ['t', 't', 't', 't', 't', 't'] 
joined = ' '.join(var)
print(joined)
print(type(joined))
```

> t t t t t t
>
> class 'str'